# I'm trying to write/paste data I have scraped into a specific excel spreadsheet cell location, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I have written some code that allows me to me to scrape data from a website using selenium and then display the specific data in CMD. I have tried a few methods to write this data or append it to a spreadsheet but none have worked. I keep receiving `invalid syntax errors`.

I have attempted three methods, this being my third:

```
with open("results.xlsx", "a") as f:
        for i in range(values):
            f.write(values "\n")
```

I really thought this block would work and don't know why invalid syntax is being displayed.

import csv
    import os
    from selenium import webdriver - part of code

```
ticker = input("Enter your ticker: ")

url = "http://financials.morningstar.com/cash-flow/cf.html?t=" + ticker.upper()
print(url)
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)

values_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='data_i97']")
values = [x.text for x in values_element]

print('Cash Flows:')
print (values[0])

with open("results.xlsx", "a") as f:
    for i in range(values):
        f.write(values "\n")

browser.close()
```

I was expecting this block of code

```
    with open("results.xlsx", "a") as f:
    for i in range(values):
        f.write(values "\n")
```

to write to my excel file. I didn't care where it wrote to on the excel spreadsheet, I just want it to write anywhere as proof of concept, but it doesn't. Instead, when I run my `py` file in `CMD` I receive

> line 21
>       f.write(values "\n")
>                         ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm not sure where to go from here, I am very new to coding, this is my first attempt. Any well written detailed sources on writing scraped data to excel or an explanation on why my code isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a concatenation element in the write line.  Try something like `f.write(values + "\n")`.  But I don't think that will give you exactly what you want.  I think you want `f.write(values[i] + "\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be.

```
for i in range(len(values)):
   f.write(values[i] + "\n")
```

Comment: You're the best. That fixed the syntax error and the code executes but it still doesn't write the scraped website data anywhere in the excel file. You got anything for why that might be? Thanks for the response, very helpful!

Comment: Making progress :0 got it to work, thank you so much!

Comment: I will when my reputation gets to 15, I give you my word.